# FreeBSD Ethernet NIC driver not recognized

Tags: drivers, freebsd, ethernet, realtek

### [Intel Motherboard GA-H61N-D2V](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4214#ov)

```
$ pciconf -l -v
re0@pci0:1:0:0: class=0x020000 card=0xe0001458 chip=0x816810ec rev=0x06 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Realtek Semiconductor'
    device     = 'Gigabit Ethernet NIC(NDIS 6.0) (RTL8168/8111/8111c)'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
```

### FreeBSD 8.2 RELEASE

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD qb91.anybots.com 8.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE #0: Fri Feb 18 02:24:46 UTC 2011     root@almeida.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  i386
```

### Kernel message

```
re0: <RealTek 8168/8111 B/C/CP/D/DP/E PCIe Gigabit Ethernet> port 0xee00-0xeeff mem 0xfbdff000-0xfbdfffff,0xfbdf8000-0xfbdfbfff irq 16 at device 0.0 on pci1
re0: Using 1 MSI messages
re0: Chip rev. 0x2c800000
re0: MAC rev. 0x00000000
re0: Unknown H/W revision: 0x2c800000
```

... when firing `ifconfig`, `re0` doesn't show up.

Unfortunately upgrading FreeBSD is not an option, I must stick to 8.2 RELEASE.

How may I troubleshoot/fix this issue?

### UPDATE - COMPILED NEW DRIVER

Followed steps in this [thread](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2011-June/062886.html).

On FreeBSD 8.2 RELEASE Virtual Machine, I recompiled the kernel. 
Then I collected `if_re.ko` and `if_re.ko.symbols` and copied them onto the machine that has the problem in `/boot/kernel/` folder.

After a reboot the problem persists.

### UPDATE - LOADER.CONF

Add `if_re_load="YES"` in `/boot/loader.conf`

```
# kldstat
Id Refs Address    Size     Name
 1   43 0xc0400000 bd97b4   kernel
 2    1 0xc0fda000 1126c    if_run.ko
 3    1 0xc0fec000 4be0     umodem.ko
 4    1 0xc0ff1000 e618     snd_uaudio.ko
 5    3 0xc1000000 56794    sound.ko
 6    1 0xc1057000 2c38     coretemp.ko
 7    1 0xc105a000 c108     ahci.ko
 8    1 0xc1067000 4c04     cuse4bsd.ko
 9    1 0xc106c000 3ce0     runfw.ko
10    1 0xc1070000 3c98     uanypkt.ko
11    1 0xc1074000 69d4     usie.ko
12    1 0xc4f0f000 9000     tmpfs.ko
13    1 0xc51b0000 26000    linux.ko
```

Still no luck.

Also tried loading manually:

```
# kldload -v /boot/kernel/if_re.ko
kldload: can't load /boot/kernel/if_re.ko: File exists
```

Not sure what this means, I suppose it means that it was loaded (?)

```
# kldstat -v | grep ko
 2    1 0xc0fda000 1126c    if_run.ko (/boot/kernel/if_run.ko)
 3    1 0xc0fec000 4be0     umodem.ko (/boot/kernel/umodem.ko)
 4    1 0xc0ff1000 e618     snd_uaudio.ko (/boot/kernel/snd_uaudio.ko)
 5    3 0xc1000000 56794    sound.ko (/boot/kernel/sound.ko)
 6    1 0xc1057000 2c38     coretemp.ko (/boot/kernel/coretemp.ko)
 7    1 0xc105a000 c108     ahci.ko (/boot/kernel/ahci.ko)
 8    1 0xc1067000 4c04     cuse4bsd.ko (/boot/modules/cuse4bsd.ko)
 9    1 0xc106c000 3ce0     runfw.ko (/boot/kernel/runfw.ko)
10    1 0xc1070000 3c98     uanypkt.ko (/boot/modules/uanypkt.ko)
11    1 0xc1074000 69d4     usie.ko (/boot/modules/usie.ko)
12    1 0xc4f0f000 9000     tmpfs.ko (/boot/kernel/tmpfs.ko)
13    1 0xc51b0000 26000    linux.ko (/boot/kernel/linux.ko)
```

### UPDATE - re0 is not UP

Instead of copying only `if_re.ko` files, I ended up copying the whole `kernel` directory

Now the adapter is UP and get an address assigned

```
re0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=389b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,WOL_UCAST,WOL_MCAST,WOL_MAGIC>
    ether 74:d4:35:12:ce:d6
    inet 10.10.99.115 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 10.10.255.255
    media: Ethernet autoselect (none)
    status: no carrier
```

But I still get these messages from the kernel, which bothers me a little. Looks like the re0 is not entirely recognized.

```
# dmesg | grep re0
re0: <RealTek 8168/8111 B/C/CP/D/DP/E PCIe Gigabit Ethernet> port 0xee00-0xeeff mem 0xfbdff000-0xfbdfffff,0xfbdf8000-0xfbdfbfff irq 16 at device 0.0 on pci1
re0: Using 1 MSI messages
re0: Chip rev. 0x2c800000
re0: MAC rev. 0x00000000
re0: Unknown H/W revision: 0x2c800000
device_attach: re0 attach returned 6
re0: <RealTek 8168/8111 B/C/CP/D/DP/E PCIe Gigabit Ethernet> port 0xee00-0xeeff mem 0xfbdff000-0xfbdfffff,0xfbdf8000-0xfbdfbfff irq 16 at device 0.0 on pci1
re0: Using 1 MSI-X message
re0: turning off MSI enable bit.
re0: Chip rev. 0x2c800000
re0: MAC rev. 0x00000000
miibus0: <MII bus> on re0
re0: Ethernet address: 74:d4:35:12:ce:d6
re0: [ITHREAD]
re0: <RealTek 8168/8111 B/C/CP/D/DP/E PCIe Gigabit Ethernet> port 0xee00-0xeeff mem 0xfbdff000-0xfbdfffff,0xfbdf8000-0xfbdfbfff irq 16 at device 0.0 on pci1
re0: Using 1 MSI-X message
re0: Chip rev. 0x2c800000
re0: MAC rev. 0x00000000
miibus0: <MII bus> on re0
re0: Ethernet address: 74:d4:35:12:ce:d6
re0: [ITHREAD]
re0: <RealTek 8168/8111 B/C/CP/D/DP/E PCIe Gigabit Ethernet> port 0xee00-0xeeff mem 0xfbdff000-0xfbdfffff,0xfbdf8000-0xfbdfbfff irq 16 at device 0.0 on pci1
re0: Using 1 MSI-X message
re0: Chip rev. 0x2c800000
re0: MAC rev. 0x00000000
miibus0: <MII bus> on re0
re0: Ethernet address: 74:d4:35:12:ce:d6
re0: [ITHREAD]
```

Comment: That means the `re` driver is already built into the kernel. I think, if possible, you need to try rebuilding the kernel on the affected system to ensure the version of the driver that gets built in to the kernel is from the updated source files.

Comment: Would it help to copy the kernel? I don't think I will be able to build on the affected system, it has limited resource (it's a long story)

Comment: A GENERIC kernel with the updated `re` should work OK, if it's going to work at all!

Comment: In fact I just ended copying the whole kernel folder and `re0` finally came up. But I am still getting Kernel messages that do bother me, but they may be just saying that all is fine now (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this revision of the chipset is supported by the stock `re` driver in version 8.2-RELEASE or earlier. You can grab a back-ported version of the driver and rebuild your kernel to include it. A quick search of the FreeBSD mailing list archive turns up this [thread](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2011-September/063855.html), which has links to the updated driver files. If you need pointers on rebuilding your kernel, [Chapter 9](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/kernelconfig.html) in the FreeBSD Handbook is a good starting point.

Comment: Yes and this [thread](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2011-June/062886.html) was helpful too. I was able to compile and collected the `if_re.ko` and `if_re.ko.symbols` copied them to the machine that needed to be patched. After a reboot, still no luck. So I must be missing a step.

Comment: I have updated my Question with my new findings

Comment: Does the `re` driver show up if you run `kldstat`? If not, try adding `if_re_load="YES"` to your `/boot/loader.conf` and reboot.

Comment: No it doesn't. I have added `if_re_load="YES"` but it didn't help. I will update the question with my results

Comment: I also tried loading manually but I am getting `kldload: can't load /boot/kernel/if_re.ko: File exists`. See update in my question